# default initialization для std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

Можно ли как-то проинициализировать `n` элементов `std::vector<int>` по-умолчанию, т.е. чтобы он содержал `n` неинициализированных значений, а не `n` нулей? Рассматриваются любые легальные варианты (замена аллокатора? доступ к внутренней памяти?).

Comment: Где-то на английском SO видел вариант с заменой аллокатора, попробую найти.

Comment: Нашел: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21028912/2752075 Правда, у меня он все равно выдает нули...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Можно заменить int на структуру с соответствующим конструктором, не инициализирующим значение. Например:

```
struct t_int
{
    int value;

    t_int() {} // Uninitilaized 'value' !

    t_int(int i) : value(i) {}
    t_int(const t_int& i) =default;
    t_int(t_int&& i) =default;

    operator int() const { return value; }
};

// test:
int main()
{
    { std::vector< t_int > test = { 1,2,3,4 }; }
    std::vector< t_int > test(4);
    cout << test[0]<<test[1]<<test[2]<<test[3] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в классе всё равно будут гарантированные нули

Comment: @Сергей Не должны быть.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat когда класс `A a{};` инициализируется так, то все его поля иницициализируются нулями (своими дефолтами), а не неинициализированными значениями

Comment: @Сергей Это происходит только если конструтор `A` был сгенерирован автоматически, либо если он был объявлен как `= default` в теле класса.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен [reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve). Вы не хотите инициализировать элементы, Вы хотите выделить память под них.

В противном случае не понятно, что именно Вы хотите. Вы пишите:

> Можно ли как-то проинициализировать n элементов std::vector по-умолчанию, т.е. чтобы он содержал n неинициализированных значений, а не n нулей?

Т.е. Вы хотите проинициализировать n элементов, но так, чтобы они остались неинициализированными :)

Upd.: на данный момент я пришел к выводу, что использование custom-аллокатора в данном случае не поможет:

1. Используем тип аллокатор как параметр шаблона класса `std::vector` - очевидно, что это никак не поможет, потому что конструктор по-умолчанию __vector_base никак не использует аллокатор, соответственно, мы не сможем переопределить поведение при вызове конструктора (по-умолчанию) класса `std::vector`.
2. Используем конструктор, который принимает аллокатор в качестве аргумента - будет вызван следующий конструктор класса __vector_base:

---

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
__vector_base<_Tp, _Allocator>::__vector_base(const allocator_type& __a)
    : __begin_(nullptr),
      __end_(nullptr),
      __end_cap_(nullptr, __a)
{
}
```

Как видите, аллокатор используется только в одном месте - в конструкторе __end_cap. __end_cap это объект класса __compressed_pair, который, очевидно, не может содержать какие-либо вызовы для аллоцирования памяти в своем конструкторе.

Таким образом, если у нас нет таких "точек", в которых мы бы могли повлиять на аллокацию памяти для вектора при вызове конструктора по-умолчанию (или с одним параметром - аллокатором), нет и смысла использовать custom-аллокатор для Вашей проблемы.

Без сомнений, **я мог допустить ошибку** в своих рассуждениях - если так, с радостью услышу, как это работает на самом деле.

Comment: Я хочу сделать `default initialization` как для `int x;`

Comment: @Сергей, ок, понял Вас. Нужно подумать :) Извините, что сразу неправильно интерпретировал Ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Сергей, обновил ответ.

Comment: @isnullxbh Так вроде речь не про дефолтный конструктор вектора? Я так понял, ТС говорит про `std::vector<int> vec(n);`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, он сам написал - "Я хочу сделать default initialization".

Comment: @isnullxbh Видимо default initialization для элементов вектора (вместо value initialization), а не самого вектора.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, возможно Вы правы, но почему тогда он пишет "как для int x"? Вопрос риторический. Даже заголовок вопроса - "default initialization для std::vector".

Comment: @Сергей, Вы не могли бы внести ясность - чего именно Вы хотите (см. выше диалог с HolyBlackCat)?

Answer (score 0):

Взгляните на [данную реализацию](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/memory/UninitializedMemoryHacks.h) из библиотеки folly. Из названия следует, что это очень implementation-defined код в красивой обёртке (не без UB). Вас интересует `folly::resizeWithoutInitialization`.